# Deallocation of Integer stored on stack without any associated pointer or variable

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, stack, null-pointer

A `std::string` is allocated on the stack (automatic storage duration) and assigned to a pointer. Then the pointer will be set to null.

```
std::string* myString = &std::string("");
myString = nullptr;
```

Is `myString` immediately deallocated after the second instruction or only after the function returns respectively if it's a member after the object is destroyed.

Comment: That code won't compile. Post real code.

Comment: It compiles with VS 2015.

Comment: @user - No it doesn't, not if you set the warning level properly. VS2015 says *"warning C4238: nonstandard extension used: class rvalue used as lvalue"*. You are not allowed to use the address of a temporary.

Comment: @user1056903: That's not a real C++ compiler, unfortunately, at least not unless you configure it correctly.

Comment: Where's the integer?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a `string` to a pointer. You can however assign the adress of a `string` to a `string` pointer. Let me change your code to valid C++:

```
std::string s = "";
std::string* s_ptr = &s;
s_ptr = nullptr;
```

The fact that you you change the value of a pointer that happens to point to `s` does not affect the string at all. Imagine you write the adress of a friends house on a piece of paper. Does the house get destroyed when you erase the adress on that piece of paper? Fortunately not.

PS: Well, the limit of this analogy is that in C++ you can use "the piece of paper" and say "destroy the house at this adress" (aka `delete s_ptr`, which would be super wrong in that case, as the string the pointer is pointing to was not created via `new`). Fortunately this does not work in real life ;)

Answer (score 0):

`myString` itself does not get "deallocated" anywhere, because it was never allocated. `myString` was instantiated in automatic scope.

When the scope where `myString` was declared terminates, `myString` goes out of scope and gets destroyed. If `myString` was declared in the function's top scope, this happens when the function returns. Until its scope terminates, `myString` itself remains a valid instance of a pointer.

The first statement sets `myString` to point to a temporary object that gets immediately destroyed. The statement by itself is valid, but dereferencing the pointer from that point on will result in undefined behavior. The very next statement sets the pointer to `nullptr`, so no undefined behavior occurs.

Comment: "The statement by itself is vali…", famous last words.

Comment: I.e. exactly after the first instruction myString can point to anything, right? What is if myString is declared as member?

Comment: @user1056903 Yes, it's undefined behavior. But you should understand that this is a temporary variable that will get destructed right after its expression (before the second line will run, myString will point to an invalid address). 
As long as you don't save the return value (not its pointer), it would be destructed and get invalid.